# how can i get data from snapshot using model from firebase realtime data base in flutter and show data in grid view

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My Modle is like this and using this modle i want to get data to gridview

```
    Streamer streamerFromJson(String str) => Streamer.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String streamerToJson(Streamer data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Streamer {
  Streamer({
    this.streamerList,
  });

  Map<String, StreamerList>? streamerList;

  factory Streamer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Streamer(
        streamerList: Map.from(json["StreamerList"]).map((k, v) =>
            MapEntry<String, StreamerList>(k, StreamerList.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "StreamerList": Map.from(streamerList!)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class StreamerList {
  StreamerList({
    this.country,
    this.streamerChannel,
    this.streamerStatus,
    this.streamerThumbnail,
    this.userName,
    this.uid,
  });

  String? country;
  String? streamerChannel;
  String? streamerStatus;
  String? streamerThumbnail;
  String? userName;
  String? uid;

  factory StreamerList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StreamerList(
        country: json["Country"],
        streamerChannel: json["StreamerChannel"],
        streamerStatus: json["StreamerStatus"],
        streamerThumbnail: json["StreamerThumbnail"],
        userName: json["UserName"],
        uid: json["uid"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Country": country,
        "StreamerChannel": streamerChannel,
        "StreamerStatus": streamerStatus,
        "StreamerThumbnail": streamerThumbnail,
        "UserName": userName,
        "uid": uid,
      };
}
```

***My data from realtim data base is like***

```
{
  "StreamerList": {
    "MLwW9ym5N9WrWb0VvsoolV9goEH3": {
      "Country": "bkjb",
      "StreamerChannel": "ewedwd",
      "StreamerStatus": "Iam Boared",
      "StreamerThumbnail": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dcaomp3ex/image/upload/v1650183827/MainUserProfile/lqzkq2cg2hy8ou9lluqzxhgimic2.jpg",
      "UserName": "hjbbhb",
      "uid": "MLwW9ym5N9WrWb0VvsoolV9goEH3"
    },
    "lQzKQ2Cg2HY8oU9lluqzXHgImIc2": {
      "Country": "bkjb",
      "StreamerChannel": "ewedwd",
      "StreamerStatus": "Iam Boared",
      "StreamerThumbnail": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dcaomp3ex/image/upload/v1650183827/MainUserProfile/lqzkq2cg2hy8ou9lluqzxhgimic2.jpg",
      "UserName": "hjbbhb",
      "uid": "lQzKQ2Cg2HY8oU9lluqzXHgImIc2"
    }
  }
}
```

and also if possible i want use this model in gridview to get values only thing i want to know that how get each data from snapshot using stream builder in flutter  hope i am able to make you understand what i wanna do thanks in advance

```
class DiscoverTab extends StatelessWidget {
  DiscoverTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("StreamerList");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainuserlist = database.onValue;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainBackgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
          CustomeAppBar(),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
                stream: mainuserlist,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final myuser = snapshot.data!.snapshot;
                    // myuser.children.forEach((element) {
                    //   print(element.key);
                    // });
                    final mainValue = snapshot.data!.snapshot;

                    print(mainValue);
                    return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            mainAxisExtent: 200,
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5),
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
                          return MainCardStream(
                              image:
                                  "https://res.cloudinary.com/dcaomp3ex/image/upload/v1650183827/MainUserProfile/lqzkq2cg2hy8ou9lluqzxhgimic2.jpg",
                              country: "IN",
                              countryIcon: "in",
                              status: "sdfsdsf",
                              username: "dsjdjjs");
                        });
                  }
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I had tried to call data from streamlist.

Comment: I don't see any calls to Firebase in the code you shared. Did you try anything yet? If not, it's probably best to get started with https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/lists-of-data or one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: sir i just added the code where i had tried to get the data and i get the data as snapshot but dont know how to use snapshot in stream builder